# Protocol extension broke the compiler

Tags: swift, protocols

I try to create protocol extensions for specific struct.

```
import UIKit

struct Vas {

    let title: String
    let price: Int
    let idVas: String
    let descriptionVas: String
    let type: String
}

protocol VasCell {

    var title: String {get}
}

extension VasCell where Self: Vas {

    var title: String {
        return "text"
    }
}
```

And this code totaly broke the compiler. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: You need to be a lot more specific. What are the exact and complete error message and which lines exactly cause them?

Comment: What are you trying to do? You can't declare a property in an extension that clashes with a property that type already has like that

Comment: You should submit a bug report about it crashing the compiler though

Comment: I've tested in a Playground, it generated a crash log, reason: `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. In this context 'Vas' must be protocol too.

```
extension FirstProtocol where Self: SecondProtocol {}
```

Comment: exactly, I make ...TraitCollection protocols for this purpose. They just mirror the properties of the struct that will conform to it.

Answer (score -1):

```
struct Vas {

    let title: String
    let price: Int
    let idVas: String
    let descriptionVas: String
    let type: String
}

protocol VasCell {
    typealias T
    var title: String {get}
}

extension VasCell where T == Vas {

    var title: String {
        return "text"
    }
}

struct S: VasCell {
    typealias T = Vas
}

let s = S()
print(s.title) // text

struct S2: VasCell {
    typealias T = Int
    var title: String
}

let s2 = S2(title: "title")
print(s2.title) // title
```

Comment: Don't just post code. Provide some explanation about what was wrong and how your answer solves the issue.

Comment: Thank you. This is a good approach, but my goal was to avoid PONSO objects and create array of protocols with extensions. Generics don't solve this problem.